# xampp version to support joomla 2.5 in windows 7 32-bits

Tags: windows-7, xampp, joomla2.5

What version of Xampp do I need to download in order to run the Joomla 2.5 package in Windows 7 32-bits?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use xammp  `1.6.6a` version for run joomla 2.5 in your machine...

Comment: seems this is not working.. i just removed the latest xampp and installed the `1.6.6` buts not working